# Jquery Nested Accordion to Show Only one Level

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Suppose I have a following structure:

```
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3
        <ul>
           <li>Item11</li>
           <li>Item12</li>
           <li>Item13</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

This tree structure can have many levels.

Initially, I want to show following list:

```
Item 1

Item 2

Item 3 +
```

When I click on + list becomes

```
Item 3 -

  Item 11

  Item 12

  Item 13
```

So, parent list disappears and sublist is shown.
If I click -, then everything is returned to the previous list.

Is there some jquery plugin for doing this?

Perhaps, some options in accordion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you just want to keep creating deeper subtrees of static content or do you want to populate this with some kind of meaningful information?

Comment: Content is static. I already have this ul list.

Comment: simple, don't nest them. when item 3 is opened, hide the first according and show the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Used Dkouk his version to create what you need.

EDIT 1: Hide other menu items
EDIT 2: Second level menu

```js
$(function () {
  
 
  $('ul li').each(function () {
    if ( $(this).find('ul').length > 0 ){
    $(this).addClass('child');
  }


  
  });
  
  $('ul li.child span').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('open').find('ul').first().slideToggle();
    
           $(this).parent().siblings().slideToggle();

    
});
  
  
});
```

```css
ul { 
  list-style:none;
}
ul li.child span:after {
  content:"+";
}
ul li.child.open span:after {
  content:"-";
}
li ul { display:none; }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li>
    <span>Item 3</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li>
        <span>Item 2</span>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. When I click Item 3, Item 1 and Item 2 should disappear.

Comment: I think this should do everything you need. :)
http://codepen.io/bucky208/pen/ZOkJdy
Please remove the '-1' :(

Comment: Do you need to see the '-' and '+' visually?

Comment: i've added a second level. This is as fare as i can go i think with this menu structure (span stays visible in the main ul). Hope this helps you

Comment: I don't need to show all parents, only first. It doesn't work as expected. When I click Item3 and item2, it should show item 2 with children, but not parent of item2, namely, item3.

Comment: You can't hide the other parents if the child is inside it.
ul>li>(span+ul>li>(span+ul>li+li+li))

Answer (score -1):

You can add a class to your list when it's have a sublist, and toggle the list and toggle another class for parent of list so can change the '+' to '-'.

You can as many levels, and the code will work,
I've add a span to the list have child, but so can trigger the click only at text, if you trigger click for LI list and have sublist open then will close again.

You can style the content.
Here a simple example :

```js
 $(function () {
      
 
      $('ul li').each(function () {
        if ( $(this).find('ul').length > 0 ){
        $(this).addClass('child');
      }


      
      });
      
      $('ul li.child span').click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('open').parent().find('ul:first').slideToggle();
       $(this).parent().siblings().slideToggle();
    });
      
      
    });
```

```css
ul { 
      list-style:none;
    }
    ul li.child span:after {
      content:"+";
    }
    ul li.child span.open:after {
      content:"-";
    }
    ul li ul { display:none; }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li>
        <span>Item 3</span>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          <li>
          <span>Item 3</span>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
          </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: According to this snippet Item 1, Item 2 are visible when plus is clicked.

Comment: You can make them click, also Items 3 you can make click and slide toggle the ul child inside it.
If you want i can change the code to make it clicked, if you didn't understand how to do it

Comment: Ok, Can you mark the answer , and i'll change code now.

Comment: Could you explain to me more so can know exactly what you want.

Comment: @AndrewFount , Could you check the new code now, it's should work as you expect.